# Making vehicle using WheelColliders faster

Tags: unity, c#, physics, car

I have a driving game and use wheel colliders to control cars, but whatever I change with the WheelCollider components it doesn't get faster and is way too slow.

The code of the controller:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AxleInfo
{
public WheelCollider leftWheel;
public WheelCollider rightWheel;
public bool motor;
public bool steering;
}

public class SimpleCarController : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<AxleInfo> axleInfos;
public float maxMotorTorque;
public float maxSteeringAngle;

// finds the corresponding visual wheel
// correctly applies the transform
public void ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(WheelCollider collider)
{

    Transform visualWheel = collider.gameObject.transform;

    Vector3 position;
    Quaternion rotation;
    collider.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

    visualWheel.transform.position = position;
    visualWheel.transform.rotation = rotation;
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    float motor = maxMotorTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float steering = maxSteeringAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    foreach (AxleInfo axleInfo in axleInfos)
    {
        if (axleInfo.steering)
        {
            axleInfo.leftWheel.steerAngle = steering;
            axleInfo.rightWheel.steerAngle = steering;
        }

        if (axleInfo.motor)
        {
            axleInfo.leftWheel.motorTorque = motor;
            axleInfo.rightWheel.motorTorque = motor;
        }

        

        ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(axleInfo.leftWheel);
        ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(axleInfo.rightWheel);
    }
}
}
```

and here are the options of the WheelCollider (every wheel has the same options)...
[image]

From here I got the code by the way https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** *my original response suggested simply increasing maxMotorTorque, but it appears this has no apparent effect by itself.*

Try adding force to the parent (car_body) rigidbody along with the motor values of the wheel colliders. Something like this:

```
float motor = maxMotorTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * motor);
float steering = maxSteeringAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

You may need to lower the cg to get the car to handle the way you want.

[image: slow car 400 torque]
[image: fast car 40,000 torque]

Here's the whole script, including tweaking the Center of Mass (with magic numbers here):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class AxleInfo
{
    public WheelCollider leftWheel;
    public WheelCollider rightWheel;
    public bool motor;
    public bool steering;
}

public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text speedometer;

    public List<AxleInfo> axleInfos;
    public float maxMotorTorque;
    public float maxSteeringAngle;

    // finds the corresponding visual wheel
    // correctly applies the transform
    public void ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(WheelCollider collider)
    {
        if (collider.transform.childCount == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Transform visualWheel = collider.transform.GetChild(0);

        Vector3 position;
        Quaternion rotation;
        collider.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

        visualWheel.transform.position = position;
        visualWheel.transform.rotation = rotation;
    }

    Rigidbody rb;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.centerOfMass = new Vector3(0, -4, 0);
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float motor = maxMotorTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        speedometer.text = string.Format("motor {0:N0}\n{1:N0} mph", motor, rb.velocity.magnitude);
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * motor);
        float steering = maxSteeringAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        foreach (AxleInfo axleInfo in axleInfos)
        {
            if (axleInfo.steering)
            {
                axleInfo.leftWheel.steerAngle = steering;
                axleInfo.rightWheel.steerAngle = steering;
            }
            if (axleInfo.motor)
            {
                axleInfo.leftWheel.motorTorque = motor;
                axleInfo.rightWheel.motorTorque = motor;
            }
            ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(axleInfo.leftWheel);
            ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(axleInfo.rightWheel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but it won't get faster.
I think it has something to do with the new Physics engine unity has since v 5.

Comment: You know what -- you are right! Will revise this answer with a solution.

Comment: It finally worked. Thanks :)
Also maybe use an extra speed variable instead of the motorTorque.

Comment: Glad this helped. And yes, decoupling the force from the motorTorque seems like a good idea :-)